# Stripe Checkout - Create a Variable Charge

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I was previously charging users a fixed amount, say, "$20," but I wanted to create a donation box that would accept variables. I understand that there is "StripeCheckout.open," but does anyone know how it would look?

That being said, I am currently using the code below to charge a user a fixed amount, though I'm desperate to find out how to set a variable amount that can be charged.

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
  'email' => 'customer@example.com',
  'card'  => $token
));

$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  'customer' => $customer->id,
  'amount'   => variable,
  'currency' => 'cad'
));
?>
```

Comment: Store the `$variable` beforehand, and use it in your array? I'm not sure sure what exactly you're confused about.

Comment: Hey Amal, I set a text field on my web page for the user to specify the amount; however, when my server retrieves the information, it says "invalid amount." Very new to this and not sure how to set it up where the server finds the exact amount the person set and charges them on the card

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you probably should use V2 instead of V1, and what you want to do is something like this:

```
$('#sendPledgeBtn').click(function(){
      var token = function(res){
        var $input = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
        var tokenId = $input.val();
        var email = res.email;

        setTimeout(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url:'make-payment.php',
            cache: false,
            data:{ email : email, token:tokenId },
            type:'POST'
          })
          .done(function(data){
            // If Payment Success 
            $('#sendPledgeBtn').html('Thank You').addClass('disabled');
          })
          .error(function(){
            $('#sendPledgeBtn').html('Error, Unable to Process Payment').addClass('disabled');
          });
        },500);

        $('form:first-child').append($input).submit();
      };

      StripeCheckout.open({
        key:         'pk_live_XXXXXXXXX', // Your Key
        address:     false,
        amount:      $('#amount').val(),
        currency:    'usd',
        name:        'Canted Pictures',
        description: 'Donation',
        panelLabel:  'Checkout',
        token:       token
      });
      return false;
});
```

Comment: Hey Timothy! I'm using their embedded implementation as well as a custom form, which can be found here: www.cantedpictures.com/donate/ 

If you know a solution, and if it's no trouble, please post an example so I can tinker with it on my end.

I apologize if I'm not clear on some aspects; I'm very, very, very new to all of this.

Comment: Taking a look at it now. BTW, one of your jquery files is returning a 404 (you also seem to be loading a duplicate instance). Right now I'm looking at your process going backwards from Stripe.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It's been exhaustive trying to put things together with no experience. Going to remove the duplicate now.

Comment: Hey Timothy,

Thanks again for the code. Just wondering, do you know how I might validate this on the server side?

Comment: You need to grab the Stripe PHP lib from here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php